# unpivot data and change the resulting blanks to zero in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have some some data which I unpivot them in the query editor and I try to use them I found a lot of blanks which i need to change them to zero

made some measures which explained in the web and try to add zero to the column with no luck to reach out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please accept it to mark item as solved

Answer (score 0):

You say " lot of blanks" but I am fairly sure that any nulls would be suppressed during an unpivot.

However, to try what you suggest, right click the desired columns, replace values, then replace **A** with **zero**

Then go back and modify the code in formula bar or in home...advanced editor... changing the **A** to **null** so that

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","A",0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"})
```

becomes

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"})
```

Im guessing however they are not real blanks. If above does not work try using **""** instead of null, and if that doesnt work try a line feed **#(lf)** carriage return **#(cr)** or tab **#(tab)**

[image]

Comment: the blanks appeared after the unpivot and while I try to use the data in a table to visualize it, I want to change them to 0 instead of these blanks.